# Multiple outer merges in python pandas

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I am trying to merge some dataframes based on specific column. Each dataframe is consisted of two columns.

I can do the merge for two of them. But When i get the result and try to do the next merge I have problem with the suffixes:

The first is fine:

```
l  = pd.merge(d2700, d2701, on='gene_id', how='outer', left_index=False, suffixes=['_2700', '_2701'])
```

In the second I can't name the suffixes...

```
l1  = pd.merge(l, d2702, on='gene_id', how='outer', left_index=False)
```

Because if I do I get an error like:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Edit:
I am editing the initial message as I figured out what was the problem.
The names of the columns of the dataframe were the same, so it was not possible to merge them. 
But if you name the columns with different name, then there is no problem nmerging multiple of them.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce with a simple example. You'll need to post a some example dataframes and your desired output.